# Set starting position for drag event

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-ui, drag-and-drop

I would like to set the start position when I click into the parent area (div id content in the example) and set it as a start position for a drag event.

Is that possible?

Thanks.

I already have: [JSFiddle Link](http://jsfiddle.net/5ZVe6/28/)

Comment: I don't think jQuery UI provides for this.. almost seems worth it to code your own dragging functions to get this to work :S

Comment: But I only want to set the hands position onmousedown inside the content div. Is that so difficult?

Comment: [That is not difficult](http://jsfiddle.net/6Gaze/).  Making it play nicely with draggable, however, is.

Comment: Thanks Joseph I think you are right.. It is not working nicely.

Comment: Any suggestions on how to fix that?

Comment: unfortunately I can't figure it out atm :S

Comment: I found the solution. Thanks guys:) Thanks a lot:)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Not sure if this is what you want, but check [jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/skram/5ZVe6/43/) here

**Edit**: Good catch, updated the code for handling the clicks. Check the updated link and let me know.

Comment: Thanks mate:) Excellent! I found a different solution using mousedown, mousemove and mouseup but your solutions seems to be much cleaner! Thanks. PS.There is a problem with your code when someone just clicks in the content div without dragging anything. try it!

Comment: Please check it again if you can fix that as well.

Comment: I have updated the code to handle the clicks. I had to use the mouse down, mouse move and mouse up to identify if it is just a click or mouse down + mouse move. Hope it help!

Answer (score 0):

Update below style to take the hand at center position:

```
#content div{margin:100px auto;}
```

You can increase the 100px to the amount you want :)

Comment: But I do not want to take it at the center. I want to be able to start from any position inside content div.